# Outlook background image

Tags: html, css, outlook

Why would this not work, I can't get background-repeat to stop tiling in Outlook html emailer.

```
<body style="background-image:url(http://www.blaaa.com/email-bg.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat"></body>
```

Comment: Background images in an e-mail are not a very good idea. Lots of clients will ignore them or do weird things with them. Try to stick to inline images and flat background colours for your text cells.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Full Width Backgrounds on Outlook '07/'10/'13](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280715/full-width-backgrounds-on-outlook-07-10-13)

Answer (score 3):

There's no point in using background-images for E-Mails, because they are not supported widely  by the email clients (Outlook, Hotmail, Gmail ...)

See here for what you can have in E-Mails
http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

Seperate the styles with ; not ,

```
style="background-image:url(http://www.blaaa.com/email-bg.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat"
```

Comment: Tried that also but didn't work. It ignores the no-repeat in outlook and starts to tile

Answer (score -1):

you need to add this for outlook

background-repeat: **repeat-y** no-repeat;